# C# Compare SqlDataReader column value with 0

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldatareader

I have this bit of code:

```
// Do comparisons for highlighting
if (cellNum == reader.GetOrdinal("MTD Carryover"))
{
   tempCell.Width = 155;

   if (reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("MTD Carryover")) < 0)
   {
       tempCell.Attributes.Add("class", tempCell.Attributes["class"] + " " + "RedBackground");
   }
   else
   {
       tempCell.Attributes.Add("class", tempCell.Attributes["class"] + " " + "GreenBackground");
   }

   // Test for yellow last, MTD Carrover - 10% but still less than 0
   if (reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("MTD Carryover")) > (reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("MTD 
       Carryover")) - (reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("MTD Carryover")) * .1))
                                    && (reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("MTD Carryover")) > 0))
   {  
       tempCell.Attributes.Add("class", tempCell.Attributes["class"] + " " + "YellowBackground");
   }
}
```

I want to compare a `SqlDataReader` column value to see if it is less than than 0.  If it is, I want to make the background green, if not I want to make it red. If it is within 10% of 0 but not over 0 I want to make it yellow.

I *thought* this worked. However when I use a checkbox that reloads the page with a URL parameter I get the following error:

> Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.

I've confirmed this is the issue by removing the code and using the checkbox and reloading the page that this particular bit of code and the 0 is my real issue. I use the same code on other columns to compare with other `SqlDataReader` values and that works. This is the only area where I need to compare to something outside of the `SqlDataReader` stream.

I'm not sure how to properly compare a value from a `SqlDataReader` stream with 0.  I've tried creating an Int32 variable and setting it to 0 for the comparison but I get the same result.

```
// Used in the SqlDataReader compare below for column highlighting
Int32 compareMTDCarryover = 0;
```

I'm relatively new at C# and have been using StackOverflow extensively on my first full website. I cannot seem to find the answer to this question though. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which line throws the exception?  Are you calling `reader.Read()` somewhere?

Comment: Yes I am calling reader.Read() before this code.  I am getting data from the SqlDataReader just fine.  The line that is throwing the exception is:

 if (reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("MTD Carryover")) < 0)

Specifically the 0.  SqlDataReader seems to think I am trying to access a Sql value

Answer (score 0):

Through more examination I actually have null values in MTD Carryover field in SQL that I didn't realize I had.